# How to get the cpu current speed that just like the value diplaying in Taskmgr? the picture below

Tags: python, c++, window, wmi

like the picture below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXet8.jpg)

how can I get the value 1 (speed) but not vuale 2 (Maximum speed) by WMI or any other programming ways.

I have refered to many WMI API but can't get any answer.

Comment: Do you mean a current CPU utilisation?

Comment: no, just the speed, ~GHz

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for the CurrentClockSpeed member of the Win32_Processor class that you can query by WMI api.

Comment: thank u. I had tried this method, but it couldn't solve the problem. This class can't get the value that I want, although it has a member called CurrentClockSpeed.

Comment: When you say the value you want, how are you checking that value? Are you looking at task manager and printing from your code at the same time?